# Open Web Page in Windows 2008 R2 Task Scheduler runs forever

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task

I have a number of scheduled tasks which simply open a web page in Windows Server 2008 R2.  They used to run and end without abending, but now they open and stay open and I have to setup the task to quit them by force before their next scheduled run.  I've thought about installing CURL or WGET, but is there a way to do this with R2 without going to that step?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using WGET for Win32 and it worked flawlessly.

http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/

It was simple to download (single file) and I just had to change the program to start to the file path.